# Sort Everything After A Specific Character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am needing to sort a field on everything after a space usig SQL.  In the example below, I would like it to sort (ascending) beginning with the last name.

USA-J. Doe
USA-M. Mouse
USA-A. Mouse
USA-D. Duck
USA-P. Panther
USA-T. Bird

I need it to sort the entire string, but on the last name.  If there are two last names that are identical, I would like for it to take the initial of the first name into account.  The result would be:

USA-T. Bird
USA-J. Doe
USA-D. Duck
USA-A. Mouse
USA-M. Mouse
USA-P. Panther

I will need to use this code in both SQL Server and MS Access.

I hope that someone can fully answer this question.  For whatever reason, someone has scored me a -1 on this question.  I cannot figure out why.  I have been as specific as I know to be and I wasn't able to find an answer to the final piece--sorting by first letter if the last name is the same.

Thank you guys for responding.  The information helped.  I had to add brackets around "name" because the name of the field was similar to the name of the actual table.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: This doesn't look like it takes the first name (represented by the first letter of the name) into consideration.  In the example, there is A. Mouse and M. Mouse.  Am I wrong?

Comment: I will need to use this code in both SQL Server and MS Access.

Comment: . . I don't believe there is any way to write this using basic SQL that will work in both databases.

Comment: @Beckie you need to show what you have tried to solve the question. You haven't shown any attempts to solve it. I guess this is the reason for the downvote(-1).

Comment: +1. the question is clear enough for me.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Srikanth.  I tried so many things, I didn't want to confuse the question.  Live and learn.  Vland, thank you so much for the +1.  I really tried!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the database.  The following is how you might do this in SQL Server:

```
order by substring(name, charindex(' ', name) + 1, len(name)))
```

Similar logic works in other databases but the functions are different.

For instance, in Oracle:

```
order by substr(name, instr(name, ' ') + 1)
```

And, in MySQL, you could use similar logic, but this is simpler:

```
order by substring_index(name, ' ', -1)
```

And in MS Access:

```
order by mid(name, instr(name, ' ') + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For sorting by lasname, firstname you need to use like this in SQL server:

```
order by substring(name, charindex(' ', name) + 1, len(name))), substring(name, charindex('-', name) + 1, 1))
```

In Access

```
order by mid(name, instr(name, ' ') + 1), order by mid(name, instr(name, '-') + 1, 1)
```