# Symfony3/Doctrine : ORDER BY CASE / Specific value first

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I'm searching a solution to order my query with query builder.

I want to order my query by `ASC` but with a specific value at first place.
I know how to do this in `SQL with order by case`... but i found few solution  that don't really work with doctrine.

For example : i have a table with : A, B, D, C, F, E.

I want to sort like this : F, A, B, C, D, E

I found something like that in other topic but it doesn't work for me :

```
$qb->addSelect("(CASE When c.type like 'foo%' Then 1 WHEN c.type like 'foo1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HIDDEN type");
```

Is it possible to do something like this directly in the `orderBy` of a QueryBuilder (Doctrine) ?

Thanks for your reply

**--- EDIT ---**

I found the problem, it come from the 'group_by' option in my form. 
So here is my function in my repository :

```
public function findBolQB($username)
    {
        return $this
                ->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->innerJoin('p.program','prg')
                ->innerJoin('prg.bol','b')
                ->innerJoin('prg.user','user')
                ->innerJoin('p.part','part')
                ->addSelect("(CASE When user.username like :name Then 0 ELSE 1 END) AS HIDDEN userChancla")
                    ->setParameter(':name', $username)
                ->orderBy('userChancla')
                ->addOrderBy('b.code','ASC')
                ->addOrderBy('part.name','ASC');

    }
```

Don't forget the orderBy('userChancla') or it would not work !

The list is use in a form and is group by user so in my form builder my code is :

```
->add('bolEnBois', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'IssouChanclaBundle:Bol',
            'placeholder' =>'--- Bol---',
            'required' => false,
            'attr'=>array('class'=>'select2'),
            'query_builder' => function(BolRepository $a)use($options)
                {
                    return $a->findBolQB($options['user']);
                },
            'group_by' => function(Bol $bol)
                {
                    return $bol->getUser()->getFirstName().' '.$article->getUser()->getLastName();
                },
        ))
```

Hope it would help some of you :)

Comment: Hy Mate, Repeated question, please see this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25656883/sort-everything-after-a-specific-character-in-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Everything After A Specific Character in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25656883/sort-everything-after-a-specific-character-in-sql)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm looking for solution with doctrine, i know how to do this with SQL, but i don't understand how to do this with Doctrine

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple order by like this,

```
 $qb->addOrderBy('A', 'DESC')
    ->addOrderBy('B', 'DESC')
    ->addOrderBy('C', 'DESC');
```

...and so on. You will need to decide whether it is Ascending `ASC` or Descending `DESC`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ErwinSmout is it not? Anyway, will see what he actually meant. I will change my answer accordingly. Thank you mate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. A,B,c ... are not table, for the example that represent few data but anyway, i solve the problem. That come from the 'group_by' in my form, i edit my question to answer :)

Comment: @Zayders No worries :)